# Why is SuspendThread(or any function like this) unsafe?

Tags: multithreading, garbage-collection

I'm writing a incremental gc. When GC is searching the stack of a thread, the thread must not touch its stack. But making *all* access to stack critical section is too expensive.. So I want to suspend the thread while gc is searching its stack. But I heard `SuspendThread`(or any function like this) is **unsafe**. Why??

Comment: Where is the GC running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an unavoidable, fatal problem: What if the thread you're suspending holds a lock that the thread that suspended it needs to take, such as a lock on the memory allocator or a lock inside some system library? **Boom!**

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks. I added some more elaboration.

Comment: Umm.. In this case, after GC finished searching stack of one thread, GC resume the thread. and there's no lock like what you say in GC. therefore, in this case, can I use `SuspendThread`?

Comment: @ikh You mean your garbage collector won't call into any system libraries at all? It won't free any memory? If you can follow those rules while a thread is stopped, you *might* be okay.

Comment: um.. It seems that I should see my platform's documentation and know whether the functions GC uses does lock or not.. thank you!

Comment: @ikh Usually that documentation does not exist. You may have to tear into the source code, if it's available. Instead, do this a sensible way -- suspend the thread *with its cooperation*. Ask the thread nicely to let you know when it is not holding any lock and have it wait until you tell it to continue.

Comment: Actually, you have no choice. You *can't* suspend a thread without its cooperation. For example, say that thread decides, just as you go to suspend it, to suspend you (if you can suspend it without its cooperation, it can suspend you without yours, right?). What keeps both suspends from succeeding?

Comment: Um, in my case, I can guarantee that the GC thread is the only one which use `SuspendThread`.

Comment: And I can't suspend the thread with its cooperation. I know I should do it but I can't, so I ask that.

Comment: @ikh How? Do you know for a fact that, for example, the system libraries don't use `SuspendThread`? (Perhaps they have special knowledge that permits them to use it safely provided nobody else uses it. If you can assume nobody else uses it, why can't they?) This is unsafe, period.

Comment: @ikh Now you know why it's unsafe. You have to make assumptions like "I can do X because nobody would ever do X". Believe me, other people are making those same assumptions. This *has* caused pain. (And what happens when the next version of the system library behaves differently?)